# function is deprecated in php 7.2.2, how to fix it?

Tags: php, function

```
function selectLecturer($lecturer_id) { 
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE id='$lecturer_id'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    echo $row['name']." ".$row['surname'];

}

selectLecturer(1);
```

This was working in old PHP version, I upgrade my server to php 7.2.2, this function code is not working,
How can i fix it?

Comment: So which function is deprecated ?

Comment: given code is correct in php7 too.

Comment: This "function", creating the function; this code working perfectly on old php versions, but it is not working on php 7.2

Comment: Is this code inside a namespaced class?

Comment: No, its is individual function, this code is in another file, example: function.php, and I am trying to call this function like this: selectLecturer(1);

Comment: You should let on the *exact* warning/error message.

Comment: Where is the variable `$con` defined? As written, you are actually running `$sql=mysqli_query(NULL,"SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE id='$lecturer_id'");`

Comment: Missed global $con; Thanks to all, error is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not working" is something different than "deprecated". Not sure what version you were upgrading from, but using the `$con` variable inside the function will not work without either passing it to the function or defining it global inside the function.

```
function selectLecturer($lecturer_id) {
    global $con;

    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE id='$lecturer_id'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    echo $row['name']." ".$row['surname'];
}
```